# Java & MySQL - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Tags: java, mysql

I've got an issue and would be nice to receive feedback from you.
While updating the data of my table in MySQL, the following message appears:

> Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

The table is:

> `IdUsuari` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>     `Nickname` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
>     `DataRegistre` DATE NOT NULL,
>     `DataDarrerAcces` DATE NOT NULL,
>     `NumLlistes` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
>     `Password` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
>     `Admin` INT NOT NULL,
>     PRIMARY KEY (`IdUsuari`)

And the code:

```
public static void RegistreUsuari(int port, String ip, String nickname, String password) throws SQLException{ /*Creem un usuari*/

        java.util.Date dt = new java.util.Date(); 



        Connection conn = getConnection(port,ip);
        Statement st = null;
        st = conn.createStatement();



        String query = new String();
        /*Data*/

        java.text.SimpleDateFormat sdf = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");


        String currentTime = sdf.format(dt);
        query = "INSERT INTO usuari(Nickname, Password, DataRegistre, DataDarrerAcces, NumLlistes, Admin) VALUES('" + nickname +"','"+password+"','"+currentTime+"','"+currentTime+"',0)";
        st.executeUpdate(query); }
```

And

```
Database.RegistreUsuari(port, ip, "Elder", "hola");
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Apart from the fact that storing passwords in plaintext is a bad idea in general, you should really look into `PreparedStatement` for any sort of user input!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because You have 6 columns 6 values in your query and that's the answer.

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky I don't see how that makes it off-topic, it just means that that'S where the problem lies as you have already stated in your answer

Comment: You should be using a `PreapredStatement`, see [Using Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) for more details

Comment: @Dragondraikk in my (possibly wrong) opinion, thats just a typo not a problem; hence the light hearet close-vote. Otherwise if you search SO for this very error message that this question contains there are `408` duplicate questions to be exact which is in itself a big enough close reason.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are trying to insert 5 values to a table with 6 columns. You don't specify a value for `NumLlistes`.

If you wish the default value to be used, don't specify the `NumLlistes` column in the insert statement :

```
query = "INSERT INTO usuari(Nickname, Password, DataRegistre, DataDarrerAcces, Admin) VALUES('" + nickname +"','"+password+"','"+currentTime+"','"+currentTime+"',0)";
```